# sharing rule and OWD settings

Tags: sharing, org-wide-defaults

i have created a 2 objects with master-detailed relation, 
but when i try to change the OWD settings for a child object its not letting me change,it always shows controlled by parent,
since OWD settings cont be changed by child if its in M-D relation with std object. 
can any1 suggest me whats the solution for me to change the OWD settings for a child where both parent and child are custom objects linked by M-D relation.

Comment: Master Detail Relationship should be controlled by parent thats part of the benefits you receive from such relationship.. <br>
Explain what you are trying to achieve record visibility ? create different layout and assigned them to relevant profiles.

Answer (score 1):

As per docs : 
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en_US

> When a **custom object is on the detail side** of a master-detail
>   relationship with a **standard object**, **its organization-wide default is
>   set to Controlled by Parent and it is not editable**.

As you pointed out the above restriction is documented for a standard --> custom MD relationship, but not for a custom --> custom MD relation.

When you create a new master detail on a custom object, the system clearly prompts the user that the master controls the child's sharing settings.

```
The ownership and sharing of a detail record are determined by the master record.
```

So I feel you can never change the control a parent has on the child in a master detail relationship.

[image]